# The difference between long and int in C++

Tags: c++

Im a beginner. Could someone tell me what's the difference between long and int they both uses 4bytes of space and have the same range.

Comment: There does not need to be a difference.

Comment: ***they both uses 4bytes of space*** That is with your compiler. It does not have to be the 4 bytes

Comment: "They both uses 4bytes of space...".  No they don't! Not necessarily! For example, "int" is often 16 bits; "long" is often 64 bits.   Per the standard, "long" is *AT LEAST* as wide as an "int".  They needn't be the same, and often DIFFERENT.  It depends entirely on a) platform, and b) compiler implementation.